# Addition of two floating point numbers using shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to add two floating point numbers together using shell script. I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
    echo "2 arguments are required "
    exit
else
    x=$1
    y=$2
    sum = $x + $y
    echo ` sum = $sum | bc `
fi
```

When I provide two arguments to the command line, for example:

```
bash filename.sh 2.4 5
```

... it gives me an error: `[ 2 != 2 ] command not found`

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how you are running the script?

Comment: bash filename.sh 2.4 5

Comment: Try to execute it like `./filename.sh 2.4 5`

Comment: What is the output of `type -a bash` ?

Comment: Are you modifying the IFS variable?

Comment: If you have `ksh` and are willing to use that instead, it supports floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 9):

```
else
    echo -n "sum = "
    echo "$1 + $2" | bc
fi
```

will fix the second half of your problem that you have not yet got to. Your first problem is a mystery. "`[`" is a built-in command so unless there are quotation marks you are not showing us I can't see how it can take `[ $# != 2 ]` as a single word.

Answer (score 6):

Using `bc`:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    n="$@" 
    bc <<< "${n// /+}"
```

Supposing the script is called `add`, or for those who prefer easily pasted code try this workalike shell function : `add() { n="$@"; bc <<< "${n// /+}"; }`; both function and script work like this:

```
add 3.2 5.5
add 3.2 5.5 8.9
add {1..51}.{12..89}
```

The curly braces use [`bash` brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) to create about 4000 strings that `bc` interprets as decimal numbers ranging from *1.12* to *51.89*.

Output:

```
8.7
17.6
105436.89
```

Note how there's no need to check for two arguments:

- it can add *one* or more arguments,
- no arguments returns no output.
- it ignores ordinary strings, so `add 5 6.7 abc edf 9` returns `20.7`.
- it returns a syntax error if a number isn't right, *e.g.*: `9z`, `5.6.7`, `8..`, *etc.*

Answer (score 5):

Use this to add two floating numbers.

`echo 12.8 12.2 | awk '{print $1 + $2}'`

`Result:- 25`

Just replace the numbers with your variables.

You may use

`awk "BEGIN {print 12.8+12.2; exit}"`

Comment: best answer using a program that is still common across distros

Answer (score 3):

Your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
    echo "2 arguments are required "
    exit
else
    x=$1
    y=$2
    sum = $x + $y
    echo ` sum = $sum | bc `
fi
```

1. All variable substitutions should be double-quoted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells
2. Arithmetic comparison for inequality is done with `[ ... -ne ... ]`.
3. Diagnostic output, i.e. errors and warnings, should go to standard error.
4. When exiting on an error condition, a non-zero exit status should be returned to the calling shell.
5. Assignments do not accept spaces around `=`.

With these things in mind, your code becomes

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo >&2 'Expected two arguments'
    exit 1
fi

printf 'sum = %f\n' "$( printf '%f + %f\n' "$1" "$2" | bc )"
```

Alternatively, with a couple of `bash` extensions:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $# != 2 )); then
    echo >&2 'Expected two arguments'
    exit 1
fi

printf 'sum = %f\n' "$( bc <<<"$1 + $2" )"
```

With intermediate variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $# != 2 )); then
    echo >&2 'Expected two arguments'
    exit 1
fi

x="$1"
y="$2"
sum="$( bc <<<"$x + $y" )"
printf 'sum = %f\n' "$sum"
```

Modify the `printf` formatting string to suit your needs. If you, for example, want two decimals, use `%.2f` instead of `%f`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "2 arguments are required"
else
    x=$1
    y=$2
    sum="$x + $y"
    echo "sum = `bc <<< $sum`"
fi
```

Saving the script to `sum.sh` and executing it gives this output

```
chmod +x sum.sh
./sum.sh 2.45 2.55
sum = 5.00
```

Comment: The [`echo` in backticks](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) is a bit of a code smell.  Somehow `printf` would feel less convoluted here.

Comment: @tripleee Fixed. I am not a fan of using `printf` as on many default Linux installs `printf` was missing.

Comment: Huh?  It was specified by POSIX way, way back.  Which Linuxes are missing it?

Comment: @GMaster Find those default Linux installs and report to their maintainers that they are _seriously broken_. `printf` is a POSIX utility.

Comment: @GMaster assuming you already `chmod`'ed it.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$#" != 2 ]; then
   echo "2 arguments are required"; exit 1
else
   x=$1 y=$2
   sum="[sum=]n $x $y + 2k p"
   echo "$sum" | dc
fi
```

Result:

```
sum=7.4
```

Explanation:

```
We use the `dc` calculator by placing the two operands on the stack and
adding the two top of stack elements. And prior to adding, we place a
string `sum=` on the stack, and immediately print it which as a side effect
also removes it from the stack. The precision of the results is set to 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use `gnuplot` if it is avaliable (similar as `awk`)

```bsh
a=1.234
b=5.678
gnuplot -e "print $a+$b"
```

However, such a solution seems to be a little bit overkill :)